# MEthod not returning the correct result when inputting an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So, I have entered an array of size 8 in my main method and call this method to return the highest value score, however, it only returns 0.0.

```java
public static double Larger(double[] scoresRecived)
    {
        scoresRecived = new double[8];
        int c;
        double largestScore = 0;
        for (c = 0; c < 8; c++)
        {
            if (scoresRecived[c] > largestScore)
                largestScore = scoresRecived[c];
        }
        return largestScore;
    }
```

Comment: I think you should be returning `largestScore`

Comment: @Andrew Fey answer posted with output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the `scoresRecived` parameter locally. Just remove the `scoresRecived = new double[8];` line.

And you probably want to return `largestScore`.

```
public static double Larger(double[] scoresRecived)
{
    int c;
    double largestScore = 0.0;
    if (scoresRecived != null) {
        for (c = 0; c < scoredRecived.length; c++)
        {
            if (scoresRecived[c] > largestScore)
                largestScore = scoresRecived[c];
        }
    }
    return largestScore;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static double Larger(double[] scoresRecived)
{
    double largestScore = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (scoresRecived[i] > largestScore)
            largestScore = scoresRecived[i];
    }
    return largestScore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have re-declared the scores received after it acquires them. By doing that, you basically are ignoring the parameter input in the function (thus you have a blank array).

Remove this line and it should work

**scoresRecived = new double[8];**

You are also not returning the correct value. Change the line below...

**return largestScore;**

Also not required, but might want to use this instead for different array sizes.

**for (c = 0; c < scoresReceived.length; c++) {**

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] d = { 2.0, 4.1, 1.5, 3.5, 4.3, 5.4, 6.4, 7.3 };
        System.out.println(Larger(d));
    }

    public static double Larger(double[] scoresRecived) {
        int c;
        double largestScore = 0;
        for (c = 0 ; c < 8 ; c++) {
            if (scoresRecived[c] > largestScore)
                largestScore = scoresRecived[c];
        }
        return largestScore;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
7.3
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to reinitialize the actual parameter `scoresRecived`

currently you are reinitializing it:

scoresRecived = new double[8];

by doing this all data in the array will be lost. remove this line from code.

also in your for loop:

```
for (c = 0; c < scoresRecived.length; c++)
```

replace `c<8` with the size of the array, u will get `arrayIndexOutOfBoundException` otherwise